# How to retrieve another cookies from InternetGetCookie() when the website sets multiple cookies.

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I am trying to retrieve IE cookie using InternetGetCookie function. Problem is that this function retrieves only first cookie. I want to retrive 2nd cookie set by that website. I tried using InternetGetCookie function twice but still only the first cookie is retrieved.
What can be done to retrieve 2nd cookie?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself. For accessing cookies by name we have to use `InternetGetCookieEx()` function.